# Can we block copying and pasting of text from clipboard in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application where I need to block the user from copying the text from clipboard and pasting it. I am continuously researching on this from past two days but haven't found any proper solution yet.

please guide me ..if someone has done this before.....any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps use a TextWatcher and detect the addition of multiple characters in one go? Assuming you expect the user to type 1 character at a time. Although, this would probably be no good for predictive keyboards... scrap that idea

Comment: I have tried ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener for listening the text copied to clipboard and immediately setting primaryClip to empty string, this works fine for me. however the above listener works as long as your app is active. Is there any other way to listen the clipboard even after our app gets killed by android system or by the user ??

Answer (score 0):

I have used thew below code to resolve my problem, but this works from api level 11.
For below api level 11 I haven't found any solution yet.
Does any one knows solution for below api level 11 ??  Kindly help if anyone having idea for that..

```
primaryListener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {  

            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                    clipObject = ClipData.newPlainText("MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN", "");  
                } else if (clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_HTML)) {
                    clipObject = ClipData.newHtmlText("MIMETYPE_TEXT_HTML", "", "");
                } else if (clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_INTENT)) {
                    clipObject = ClipData.newIntent("MIMETYPE_TEXT_INTENT", null);
                } else if (clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_URILIST)) {
                    clipObject = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "MIMETYPE_TEXT_URILIST", uri);
                }

                clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipObject);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "copy/paste is blocked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```